# A movie in which martial arts plays a major role

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen a movie quite some time ago in the local channel. It was dubbed movie in the local language, so they kept the movie name as **Martial Arts**. But I don't think this is the real name of the original version. I believe it belongs to the period of 80's or 90's. I have searched with this name, but couldn't find.

Here is the plot that I remember -> Starting scene would be in some kinda police station. A notorious gang comes in and tortures police men and the head of that gang says that his lover is proved guilty just because she spat on road. While they warn the police men and come out of that building, another notorious gang(Main villain gang in the movie) confronts this gang and kill them including the gang head and his lover.

-> Next scene is in a colony where there is a huge building whose owners are somewhat an old-aged couple. A lady owner behaves so rude towards the tenants in that colony, doesn't supply proper water to them and she always compels them to pay rent arrears and she even beats her husband(lean person) often. While this goes on, an underachiever in martial arts who comes to barber shop in that colony with his fatty friend and tries to pretend and threatens that he belongs to that notorious gang so that the barber shouldn't ask his money for the service.

**The reason that I love this movie is it contains lot of humor even in the serious scenes and stunts**

I hope this information is enough to say the movie name if anyone knows this movie.

Comment: Kung Fu Hustle. Only Martial Arts & Football was enough to identify this movie. It very popular throughout the world. Great movie

Comment: @KharoBangdo Yeah, really it's a great movie.

Comment: Oh crap. I confused two movies here. Marshal arts & football was Shaolin Soccer, not Kung Fu Hustle. My bad. BTW, watch Shaolin Soccer also.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Even I got doubt why you mentioned football. I have watched only half part(up to what I described here), so I thought may be there was foot ball thingy in the remaining part. Sure will watch shaolin soccer when I get time :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like [**Kung Fu Hustle**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373074/) (2004):

> In Shanghai, China in the 1940s, a wannabe gangster aspires to join the notorious "Axe Gang" while residents of a housing complex exhibit extraordinary powers in defending their turf.

- Pig Sty Alley:

  [image: Pig Sty Alley]
- The Hero and his fat friend:

  [image: Hero and his friend]
- The Landlady:

  [image: Landlady]
- You can see **more pictures [here](http://outnow.ch/Movies/2004/KungFuHustle/Bilder/)**, or
- **Watch the trailer** on [**Youtube**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMdbXLmUgXY), or
- read a more detailed **plot summary** on [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_Hustle)

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much. But I am surprised to know that this movie was just released in 2004. Because it seems like it was shot in 80's or 90's